# Angular cypress test failing on contains class

Tags: angular, cypress, contains

I'm admittedly new, but I'm struggling through courses and documents to understand why my script fails.
The test gets to a navbar drop-down, successfully sees the item to click, and successfully clicks the selection. (Details below)
The screen is painted in two parts: a) fixed elements in the html, and b) records returned from a backend controller for the remaining items.

"a)" shows up immediately of course, and "b)" also after a "wait" see below.

Each row contains a SELECT button on the right end (it's own td /td).  THIS is what it can't find.

See the cypress list below:
The "a)" sections show and we wait for the backend to return with the "Get 200".
[image]

Scrolling the above to expose the right - bottom part only:

[image]

This shows it complaining about the .contains (no surprise)

The Cypress script code:

```
cy.get('app-navbar')
cy.contains('Project Design').click()
cy.contains('Open an Existing Project').click().wait(4000)
cy.contains('Investments').parent().contains('.btn-warning')
```

Corresponding HTML:

```
                </tr>
                <tr *ngFor="let p of nonTemplatesList" >
                    <td>{{p.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{p.title}}</td>
                    <td>{{p.description}}</td>
                   <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="ProjectTypeSelected(p.id)">Select</button></td> <<----- THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO CLICK
                </tr>
```

Since it IS findng the "Investments" element, (using Electron) I select the "parent" shown after "-contains Investments" and it highlights the entire row as I expected.

[image]

What's wrong with my selection?  (I need to click that Select to continue.)
Thanks in advance.
:-)

Answer (score 0):

It appears it has to do with the fact that Cypress is asynchronous, which is also seen where I had to do a "wait".  Somehow things aren't completing as soon as I expect.
SO... I was able to make this work by changing the above to:

```
       cy.contains('Open an Existing Project').click().then( tagA => {
        tagA.find('Investments').parent().find('.btn-warning')
    })
```

And now I can proceed.

Hope I didn't waste anyone's time.
:-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a GET request sent by your app to get all the projects. You can intercept the request and wait for it instead of the arbitrary `.wait()`.

```js
// intercept the request to wait on
cy.intercept('GET', '/api/Projects/GetAllProjects/').as('getAllProjects')
// search for app-navbar element containing 'Project Design'
cy.contains('app-navbar', 'Project Design').should('be.visible').click()
// probably should use selector to find correct element with given text
cy.contains('Open an Existing Project').should('be.visible').click()
cy.wait('@getAllProjects')
cy.contains('tr', 'Investments').find('.btn-warning')
```

I recommend reading up on the [best practices](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices) on the docs.